# Magento 2.2.4 - unable to print messages. - New Theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, addtocart, construct

I have a Module which processes a Post action, and then redirects. 
for example i am trying to overwrite - Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add

I have used my construct function and my method as below.

```
 public function __construct 
 ( \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager ) 
 {
   $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
 }

 public function method( ) {
    ..
    $message = “test message”
    $this->_messageManager->addError($message);
    ..
 }
```

on frontend , i am unable to render this message.
i have tried adding the below block in default.xml

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```